# How to attribute some fragments of names to sublists names taking elements from major list names

Tags: r, list, lapply, names

I have this kind of situation

```
list1 = list(mtcars, airquality, mtcars, airquality)
combined_list = list(list1, list1)

names(combined_list) = c('A_B','S_D')
combined_list = lapply(combined_list, function(x) 
  setNames(x, c(rep('something', 2),  rep('gotta give',2))))
```

and for each of the step here presented, I would like to learn how to add to each element of the with the same name, respectively the first and the second element separated from the underscore, which is named the first list with

This means for example to obtain for `list[[1]]` = A_B`

```
something_A
something_B
gotta give_A
gotta give_B

 list[[2]] = S_D

something_S
something_D
gotta give_S
gotta give_D
```

I am trying something like this to generate the name but it does not follows the desired sequence

```
lapply(seq(1:2), function(i) {lapply(seq(1:2), \(j)
  c(paste0(rep('something', 2), strsplit(names(combined_list), '_')[[j]][i]),  
    paste0(rep('gotta give',2), strsplit(names(combined_list), '_')[[j]][i])))})
```

Comment: it's bad practice to give things the same name as R functions. I would recommend going forward not naming things `list`, `c` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LETTERS` and `paste()` to generate names for `setNames()`

```
purrr::map(list(list1, list1), \(x) setNames(x, paste(c('something','gotta give'), rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 2), sep = '_')))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$something_A
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

[[1]]$`gotta give_A`
    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1      41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2      36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3      12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4      18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5      NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6      28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
7      23     299  8.6   65     5   7
8      19      99 13.8   59     5   8
9       8      19 20.1   61     5   9
10     NA     194  8.6   69     5  10
11      7      NA  6.9   74     5  11
12     16     256  9.7   69     5  12
13     11     290  9.2   66     5  13
14     14     274 10.9   68     5  14
15     18      65 13.2   58     5  15
16     14     334 11.5   64     5  16
17     34     307 12.0   66     5  17
18      6      78 18.4   57     5  18
19     30     322 11.5   68     5  19
20     11      44  9.7   62     5  20
21      1       8  9.7   59     5  21
22     11     320 16.6   73     5  22
23      4      25  9.7   61     5  23
24     32      92 12.0   61     5  24
25     NA      66 16.6   57     5  25
26     NA     266 14.9   58     5  26
27     NA      NA  8.0   57     5  27
28     23      13 12.0   67     5  28
29     45     252 14.9   81     5  29
30    115     223  5.7   79     5  30
31     37     279  7.4   76     5  31
32     NA     286  8.6   78     6   1
33     NA     287  9.7   74     6   2
34     NA     242 16.1   67     6   3
35     NA     186  9.2   84     6   4
36     NA     220  8.6   85     6   5
37     NA     264 14.3   79     6   6
38     29     127  9.7   82     6   7
39     NA     273  6.9   87     6   8
40     71     291 13.8   90     6   9
41     39     323 11.5   87     6  10
42     NA     259 10.9   93     6  11
43     NA     250  9.2   92     6  12
44     23     148  8.0   82     6  13
45     NA     332 13.8   80     6  14
46     NA     322 11.5   79     6  15
47     21     191 14.9   77     6  16
48     37     284 20.7   72     6  17
49     20      37  9.2   65     6  18
50     12     120 11.5   73     6  19
51     13     137 10.3   76     6  20
52     NA     150  6.3   77     6  21
53     NA      59  1.7   76     6  22
54     NA      91  4.6   76     6  23
55     NA     250  6.3   76     6  24
56     NA     135  8.0   75     6  25
57     NA     127  8.0   78     6  26
58     NA      47 10.3   73     6  27
59     NA      98 11.5   80     6  28
60     NA      31 14.9   77     6  29
61     NA     138  8.0   83     6  30
62    135     269  4.1   84     7   1
63     49     248  9.2   85     7   2
64     32     236  9.2   81     7   3
65     NA     101 10.9   84     7   4
66     64     175  4.6   83     7   5
67     40     314 10.9   83     7   6
68     77     276  5.1   88     7   7
69     97     267  6.3   92     7   8
70     97     272  5.7   92     7   9
71     85     175  7.4   89     7  10
72     NA     139  8.6   82     7  11
73     10     264 14.3   73     7  12
74     27     175 14.9   81     7  13
75     NA     291 14.9   91     7  14
76      7      48 14.3   80     7  15
77     48     260  6.9   81     7  16
78     35     274 10.3   82     7  17
79     61     285  6.3   84     7  18
80     79     187  5.1   87     7  19
81     63     220 11.5   85     7  20
82     16       7  6.9   74     7  21
83     NA     258  9.7   81     7  22
84     NA     295 11.5   82     7  23
85     80     294  8.6   86     7  24
86    108     223  8.0   85     7  25
87     20      81  8.6   82     7  26
88     52      82 12.0   86     7  27
89     82     213  7.4   88     7  28
90     50     275  7.4   86     7  29
91     64     253  7.4   83     7  30
92     59     254  9.2   81     7  31
93     39      83  6.9   81     8   1
94      9      24 13.8   81     8   2
95     16      77  7.4   82     8   3
96     78      NA  6.9   86     8   4
97     35      NA  7.4   85     8   5
98     66      NA  4.6   87     8   6
99    122     255  4.0   89     8   7
100    89     229 10.3   90     8   8
101   110     207  8.0   90     8   9
102    NA     222  8.6   92     8  10
103    NA     137 11.5   86     8  11
104    44     192 11.5   86     8  12
105    28     273 11.5   82     8  13
106    65     157  9.7   80     8  14
107    NA      64 11.5   79     8  15
108    22      71 10.3   77     8  16
109    59      51  6.3   79     8  17
110    23     115  7.4   76     8  18
111    31     244 10.9   78     8  19
112    44     190 10.3   78     8  20
113    21     259 15.5   77     8  21
114     9      36 14.3   72     8  22
115    NA     255 12.6   75     8  23
116    45     212  9.7   79     8  24
117   168     238  3.4   81     8  25
118    73     215  8.0   86     8  26
119    NA     153  5.7   88     8  27
120    76     203  9.7   97     8  28
121   118     225  2.3   94     8  29
122    84     237  6.3   96     8  30
123    85     188  6.3   94     8  31
124    96     167  6.9   91     9   1
125    78     197  5.1   92     9   2
126    73     183  2.8   93     9   3
127    91     189  4.6   93     9   4
128    47      95  7.4   87     9   5
129    32      92 15.5   84     9   6
130    20     252 10.9   80     9   7
131    23     220 10.3   78     9   8
132    21     230 10.9   75     9   9
133    24     259  9.7   73     9  10
134    44     236 14.9   81     9  11
135    21     259 15.5   76     9  12
136    28     238  6.3   77     9  13
137     9      24 10.9   71     9  14
138    13     112 11.5   71     9  15
139    46     237  6.9   78     9  16
140    18     224 13.8   67     9  17
141    13      27 10.3   76     9  18
142    24     238 10.3   68     9  19
143    16     201  8.0   82     9  20
144    13     238 12.6   64     9  21
145    23      14  9.2   71     9  22
146    36     139 10.3   81     9  23
147     7      49 10.3   69     9  24
148    14      20 16.6   63     9  25
149    30     193  6.9   70     9  26
150    NA     145 13.2   77     9  27
151    14     191 14.3   75     9  28
152    18     131  8.0   76     9  29
153    20     223 11.5   68     9  30

[[1]]$something_B
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

[[1]]$`gotta give_B`
    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1      41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2      36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3      12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4      18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5      NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6      28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
7      23     299  8.6   65     5   7
8      19      99 13.8   59     5   8
9       8      19 20.1   61     5   9
10     NA     194  8.6   69     5  10
11      7      NA  6.9   74     5  11
12     16     256  9.7   69     5  12
13     11     290  9.2   66     5  13
14     14     274 10.9   68     5  14
15     18      65 13.2   58     5  15
16     14     334 11.5   64     5  16
17     34     307 12.0   66     5  17
18      6      78 18.4   57     5  18
19     30     322 11.5   68     5  19
20     11      44  9.7   62     5  20
21      1       8  9.7   59     5  21
22     11     320 16.6   73     5  22
23      4      25  9.7   61     5  23
24     32      92 12.0   61     5  24
25     NA      66 16.6   57     5  25
26     NA     266 14.9   58     5  26
27     NA      NA  8.0   57     5  27
28     23      13 12.0   67     5  28
29     45     252 14.9   81     5  29
30    115     223  5.7   79     5  30
31     37     279  7.4   76     5  31
32     NA     286  8.6   78     6   1
33     NA     287  9.7   74     6   2
34     NA     242 16.1   67     6   3
35     NA     186  9.2   84     6   4
36     NA     220  8.6   85     6   5
37     NA     264 14.3   79     6   6
38     29     127  9.7   82     6   7
39     NA     273  6.9   87     6   8
40     71     291 13.8   90     6   9
41     39     323 11.5   87     6  10
42     NA     259 10.9   93     6  11
43     NA     250  9.2   92     6  12
44     23     148  8.0   82     6  13
45     NA     332 13.8   80     6  14
46     NA     322 11.5   79     6  15
47     21     191 14.9   77     6  16
48     37     284 20.7   72     6  17
49     20      37  9.2   65     6  18
50     12     120 11.5   73     6  19
51     13     137 10.3   76     6  20
52     NA     150  6.3   77     6  21
53     NA      59  1.7   76     6  22
54     NA      91  4.6   76     6  23
55     NA     250  6.3   76     6  24
56     NA     135  8.0   75     6  25
57     NA     127  8.0   78     6  26
58     NA      47 10.3   73     6  27
59     NA      98 11.5   80     6  28
60     NA      31 14.9   77     6  29
61     NA     138  8.0   83     6  30
62    135     269  4.1   84     7   1
63     49     248  9.2   85     7   2
64     32     236  9.2   81     7   3
65     NA     101 10.9   84     7   4
66     64     175  4.6   83     7   5
67     40     314 10.9   83     7   6
68     77     276  5.1   88     7   7
69     97     267  6.3   92     7   8
70     97     272  5.7   92     7   9
71     85     175  7.4   89     7  10
72     NA     139  8.6   82     7  11
73     10     264 14.3   73     7  12
74     27     175 14.9   81     7  13
75     NA     291 14.9   91     7  14
76      7      48 14.3   80     7  15
77     48     260  6.9   81     7  16
78     35     274 10.3   82     7  17
79     61     285  6.3   84     7  18
80     79     187  5.1   87     7  19
81     63     220 11.5   85     7  20
82     16       7  6.9   74     7  21
83     NA     258  9.7   81     7  22
84     NA     295 11.5   82     7  23
85     80     294  8.6   86     7  24
86    108     223  8.0   85     7  25
87     20      81  8.6   82     7  26
88     52      82 12.0   86     7  27
89     82     213  7.4   88     7  28
90     50     275  7.4   86     7  29
91     64     253  7.4   83     7  30
92     59     254  9.2   81     7  31
93     39      83  6.9   81     8   1
94      9      24 13.8   81     8   2
95     16      77  7.4   82     8   3
96     78      NA  6.9   86     8   4
97     35      NA  7.4   85     8   5
98     66      NA  4.6   87     8   6
99    122     255  4.0   89     8   7
100    89     229 10.3   90     8   8
101   110     207  8.0   90     8   9
102    NA     222  8.6   92     8  10
103    NA     137 11.5   86     8  11
104    44     192 11.5   86     8  12
105    28     273 11.5   82     8  13
106    65     157  9.7   80     8  14
107    NA      64 11.5   79     8  15
108    22      71 10.3   77     8  16
109    59      51  6.3   79     8  17
110    23     115  7.4   76     8  18
111    31     244 10.9   78     8  19
112    44     190 10.3   78     8  20
113    21     259 15.5   77     8  21
114     9      36 14.3   72     8  22
115    NA     255 12.6   75     8  23
116    45     212  9.7   79     8  24
117   168     238  3.4   81     8  25
118    73     215  8.0   86     8  26
119    NA     153  5.7   88     8  27
120    76     203  9.7   97     8  28
121   118     225  2.3   94     8  29
122    84     237  6.3   96     8  30
123    85     188  6.3   94     8  31
124    96     167  6.9   91     9   1
125    78     197  5.1   92     9   2
126    73     183  2.8   93     9   3
127    91     189  4.6   93     9   4
128    47      95  7.4   87     9   5
129    32      92 15.5   84     9   6
130    20     252 10.9   80     9   7
131    23     220 10.3   78     9   8
132    21     230 10.9   75     9   9
133    24     259  9.7   73     9  10
134    44     236 14.9   81     9  11
135    21     259 15.5   76     9  12
136    28     238  6.3   77     9  13
137     9      24 10.9   71     9  14
138    13     112 11.5   71     9  15
139    46     237  6.9   78     9  16
140    18     224 13.8   67     9  17
141    13      27 10.3   76     9  18
142    24     238 10.3   68     9  19
143    16     201  8.0   82     9  20
144    13     238 12.6   64     9  21
145    23      14  9.2   71     9  22
146    36     139 10.3   81     9  23
147     7      49 10.3   69     9  24
148    14      20 16.6   63     9  25
149    30     193  6.9   70     9  26
150    NA     145 13.2   77     9  27
151    14     191 14.3   75     9  28
152    18     131  8.0   76     9  29
153    20     223 11.5   68     9  30
etc.
```

Comment: note, I used map here, but it's exactly the same with any *apply() function :-) (more or less)

Comment: @thank you so much. Actually I was looking for something more general in a way that I could get everytime a different element before and after the _ in the name of the general list, since those names are different

Comment: can you give an example? E.g. in the code in your question, what would it instead look like?

Comment: I added the example for list2, how it should look like

Comment: I do not know whether it is possible to modify your code...just slightly